# In HandleValidSubmitAsync() if an exception is thrown, do I need to await any open tasks?

Tags: async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

This is for Blazor (server). In my `HandleValidSubmitAsync()` I have a list of tasks that are for BLOBs I am uploading. If there is no exception, I do the following before returning:

```
await Task.WhenAll(listTasks);
```

Do I need to put that in a `finally` so it is called if an `Exception` is thrown? Or can I ignore them? I don't take any action on their completion, and in the finally, if they throw an exception, I won't catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to put that in a finally so it is called if an Exception is thrown?

No, when an there is an exception you are already in 'invalid state' territory. It won't help to add another Task and maybe start some.

I would normally put it inside a try/catch and handle the invalid state but maybe you don't need that.

It could be a good idea to make your [uploads cancellable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#cancel-a-file-upload) but I have not done that myself (yet). If so then put the Cancel() in the catch block.